# Как обработать URL?

Tags: url, php

Когда пользователь заходит на URL: `http://www.mysite.ru/page/news001/`
как из url взять 'news001'?

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/search/?q=%D0%A7%D0%9F%D0%A3&t=question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого есть `mod_rewrite` в файле .htaccess. После манипуляций данные из URL можно будет получить как обычный `GET`.

Answer (score 4):

Какой вопрос -- такой ответ)

```
$myPath = explode("/", $SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
echo $myPath[1];
```

Answer (score -1):

Можно юзать `.htaccess + rewriterule ^page/([\w+])/ /index.php?page=$1`, тогда в индексном файле можно взять из `$_GET['page']`, только я не уверен на счёт правила `^page/([\w+])/`, не особо шарю в регулярках. Нужно тестить.